# What MIME type should I use for an MPP file?

Tags: mime-types, ms-project

I have seen an example of what i intend to do from this question [uploading documents to sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917038/uploading-documents-in-sql-server-2008-using-asp-net-c-sharp) i have this working fine, but how would you upload an .mpp file? What would be the type be for it I have been searching for a while but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Just to point out, this question doesn't really warrant any of those tags. This is a simple question about which MIME type to use for a specific file, and is irrelevant to what you just so happen to be doing with the value.

Comment: hi, i thought id use the tags as I'm coding in c# and asp, I'm new to the site so I'm still learning.  Sorry

Comment: BTW, based on you old tags, you may be interested in [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81283/asp-net-how-to-detect-file-upload-mime-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As detailed [here](http://filext.com/file-extension/MPP), you can see a few different MIME types that could be used. The following is that list:

> application/vnd.ms-project, application/msproj, application/msproject,
>   application/x-msproject, application/x-ms-project,
>   application/x-dos_ms_project, application/mpp,
>   zz-application/zz-winassoc-mpp

NOTE: "MIME type for [File Extension]" is a good phrase to use when searching for these things

Comment: Hi Many thanks, I've just this second found the link you supplied via google!! But thanks!

Comment: I like the note, I googled exactly that, and this was the first search result!